# C2678 - no operator found

Tags: c++, binary-operators

If I try to compile I get the following error:
C2678

```
binary '-': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const D3O::Point' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

code creating error:

```
forward_list<double> anglelist;
anglelist.resize(pointlist.max_size());
angleto angleTo;
double test = angleTo(pointlist.front(), angleReference);
transform(pointlist.begin(), pointlist.end(), anglelist.begin(),bind2nd(angleTo,angleReference));
```

Definition of angleto:

```
    struct angleto : public std::binary_function<Point, Vector, const double>
{
        const double operator() (Point a, Vector b) const
             { return b.angleTo(a.ToVector());}
        };
```

Definition of angleTo:

```
const double Vector::angleTo(Vector vec)
{
    Vector zVec = this->vecProd(vec);
    Vector hVec = this->turnAroundAxisfordeg(zVec, 90);
    if (hVec.smallAngle(vec) <= 90)
    {
        return this->smallAngle(vec);
    }
    else
    {
        return (double)(360.0-this->smallAngle(vec));
    }
}
const double Vector::smallAngle(Vector vec)
{
    if ((this->value() * vec.value()) == 0)
    {
        return (double)0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 180 / M_PI * acos(this->scalar(vec) / (this->value() * vec.value()));
    }
}
const double Vector::value()
{
    return sqrt(this->X * this->X + this->Y * this->Y + this->Z * this->Z);
}
const Vector Vector::vecProd(Vector vec)
{
    return Vector(this->Y * vec.Z - this->Z * vec.Y, this->Z * vec.X - this->X * vec.Z, this->X * vec.Y - this->Y * vec.X);
}
const Vector Vector::turnAroundAxisfordeg(Vector Axis, double degrees)
{
    if (this->ColinearTo(Axis))
    {
        return Vector(this->X,this->Y,this->Z);
    }
    else
    {
        double R[3][3] = {};
        Vector axis = Axis.getUnitVector();
        double deg = degrees / 180 * M_PI;
        R[0][0] = axis.X * axis.X * (1 - cos(deg)) + cos(deg); R[0][1] = axis.X * axis.Y * (1 - cos(deg)) - axis.Z * sin(deg); R[0][2] = axis.X * axis.Z * (1 - cos(deg)) + axis.Y * sin(deg);
        R[1][0] = axis.Y * axis.X * (1 - cos(deg)) + axis.Z * sin(deg); R[1][1] = axis.Y * axis.Y * (1 - cos(deg)) + cos(deg); R[1][2] = axis.Y * axis.Z * (1 - cos(deg)) - axis.X * sin(deg);
        R[2][0] = axis.Z * axis.X * (1 - cos(deg)) - axis.Y * sin(deg); R[2][1] = axis.Z * axis.Y * (1 - cos(deg)) + axis.X * sin(deg); R[2][2] = axis.Z * axis.Z * (1 - cos(deg)) + cos(deg);
        double x = this->X * R[0][0] + this->Y * R[0][1] + this->Z * R[0][2];
        double y = this->X * R[1][0] + this->Y * R[1][1] + this->Z * R[1][2];
        double z = this->X * R[2][0] + this->Y * R[2][1] + this->Z * R[2][2];
        x = this->dRound(x, 15);
        y = this->dRound(y, 15);
        z = this->dRound(z, 15);
        return Vector(x, y, z);
    }
}
const bool Vector::ColinearTo(Vector vec)
{
    return ((this->vecProd(vec)).Value <= 1E-10);
}
const double Vector::scalar(Vector vec)
{
    return this->X * vec.X + this->Y * vec.Y + this->Z * vec.Z;
}
const Vector Vector::getUnitVector() {
    return Vector(this->X / this->value(), this->Y / this->value(), this->Z / this->value());
}
```

Definition of ToVector:

```
const Vector const Point::ToVector() { return Vector(this->X, this->Y, this->Z); }
```

Why do I get this error? I have included the operator-overwrites in the used namespace.

```
const Vector const Vector::operator- (const Vector param) { double newX, newY, newZ; newX = X - param.X; newY = Y - param.Y; newZ = Z - param.Z; return Vector(newX, newY, newZ);}
```

Do I have to pin the class variables X,Y and Z or what is the reason why I get this error? I am really confused, in all functions required to build angleTo, there is no need of any - operator, so why is it complaining about that implementation?

Comment: In Visual Studio, the "Error" window only shows summaries, and you've posted an error summary. Open the "Output" window to view the full error message, including what line the error occurs on. Right now, you've posted `Vector::operator-(const Vector param)`, but that's entirely unrelated to the problem. The line of code is looking for `D3O::Point::operator-(???)const`.  And you haven't posted any code that causes the compiler to look for that code. Please review the [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to ask a good question.

Comment: Well actually implementing the - operator correct solves the issue, and it compiles :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const Vector const Vector::operator- (const Vector param) {
```

This declares an operator where the left side must be non-const.  Ergo:

> binary '-': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const D3O::Point'.

It can't use that function because the left side is const.  I assume you meant to do this instead:

```
const Vector       Vector::operator- (const Vector param) const {
            ^pointless. remove                            ^IMPORTANT
```

Comment: I ll check, but I think that is my solution :), however I still got no clue why it calls that operator.

Comment: As far as I understand it trys to call an operator which it cant find, however this operation ain't used in the given case. Not coz there is none, but simple because there is no call to it. There are only -operators used on members of the function, which are double.

Comment: `const Vector const Vector::operator- (const Vector param)` is the same as `const Vector Vector::operator- (const Vector param)`, which is `operator-` where the left hand side is `Vector&`, and the right hand side is `const Vector`, and the return type is `const Vector`.